# Import of JavaScript module by assigning to a variable

Tags: javascript, codepen

Maybe this question is trivial, but researching in several import/export docs did not give me an answer. I am trying to understand a code snippet that starts with the following imports on a CodePen example:

```
const Point = ol.geom.Point;
const RMap = rlayers.RMap;
```

I would rather expect module imports like this:

```
import { Point } from "ol/geom";
import { RMap } from "rlayers";
```

I thought it might be related to some hidden CodePen functionality, but also could not find an explanation. The CodePen is here https://mmomtchev.github.io/rlayers/#/add_delete when you click on the CodePen button. You can see in the JS settings that the CDN https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rlayers@1.4.1 was added. But I don't see how this would allow
the syntax given above. It did also not work, when I tried on a new CodePen.

Comment: Try codesandbox. You can include packages and pre-existing frameworks to choose from.

Comment: How are they exported?

Answer (score 0):

In your Pen's settings, go to the JS panel and scroll down to add packages there. You can load in packages from Skypack that way, and they'll appear something like:

```
import * as React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import { useState } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1"
```

(or whatever you want to install)